# В spf13-vim постоянно запускается в фоне git.  Как отключить?

Tags: vim

Скачал сборку spf13-vim. Почти переключении вкладок, открытии файлов и других действиях запускается в фоновом режиме git через cmd. Из-за него всё тормозит. Подскажите где отключить.

Comment: У Вас windows? да, под ней git тормозит с ужасной силой.

Из плагинов, которые я увидел в этой сборке, похоже только vim-fugitive может приводить к подобному. Если Вам git не нужен - просто отключите его в `.vimrc.bundles`, закомментировав одну строку (просто добавив `#` в начало строки), а потом выполните команду `:BundleClean` для удаления.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ответ из комментария.

---

Из плагинов, которые я увидел в этой сборке, похоже, только *vim-fugitive* может приводить к подобному.

Если Вам *git* не нужен - просто отключите его в `.vimrc.bundles`, закомментировав одну строку (просто добавив `#` в начало строки), а потом выполните команду `:BundleClean` для удаления.